# Displaying X Co-ord & Y Co-ord of an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am moving a ball around on the screen using a method inside a scheduled timer.
I want to display the co-ordinates of the ball inside a label.

What I have is:

*.h*

```
IBOutlet UILabel *ShowX;
IBOutlet UILabel *ShowY;
```

*.m*

```
ShowX = Ball.center.X
ShowY = Ball.center.Y
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone explain why it doesn't work and give me the solution please?

:)

Comment: you are missing .text

Answer (score 1):

```
 self.ShowX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", Ball.center.X]; // or if has a frame. Ball.frame.origin.x
self.ShowY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", Ball.center.Y];
```

[Edited]

that should work

Comment: Assign a floating point number to a NSString property? I doubt that that works.

Comment: It should be small x and y.

Comment: see the question, i've just written the snippet according to the information provided to me